# Facebook style JQuery autocomplete plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

Im after a plugin to do autocomplete like facebook does in that you can select multiple items - similar to how tagging a stackoverflow question works.

Here are a couple I ran into:

- [http://wharsojo.wordpress.com/2008/02/18/jquery-facebook-autocomplete](http://wharsojo.wordpress.com/2008/02/18/jquery-facebook-autocomplete/)
- http://www.emposha.com/javascript/fcbkcomplete.html
- https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput

Have you tried any of these? Were they easy to implement and customize?

Comment: Which plugin did you used?? I am searching one which works fine in firefox and IE

Comment: Warning: I have now implemented the JQuery-tokeninput in my project, and it seems that not only that one, but all of the others mentioned here, want to put the input field on a separate line. It seems not possible to put them on the same line i.e. `To: [..the field..]`. Perhaps absolute positioning, or using tables, is the solution, but I don't really like either, but maybe I am missing something..

Comment: JQuery-tokeninput is now having a facebook style which allows to put multiple tokens on the same line. See the demo.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput

I just had a go at this one and it was really easy to implement using an asp.net page to output the JSON (from the search params)
Then theres just a few lines of Javascript you need to create it (and the settings)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Users").tokenInput("../Services/Job/UnassignedUsers.aspx?p=<%= projectID %>&j=<%= jobID %>", {
        hintText: "Begin typing the user name of the person you wish to assign.",
        noResultsText: "No results",
        searchingText: "Searching..."
    });
});
```

Comment: It also appears to have FireFox bugs

Comment: @AnApprentice: The latest version has many bug fixes.

Comment: Not support create new tag on the fly yet

Comment: loved this plugin but had to let it go for jqueryUI autocomplete since I needed on the fly support

Comment: If you are using ASP.Net you can use my opensourse project ASPTokenInput which adds server side functionality to the jquery-tokeninput plugin https://github.com/harindaka/ASPTokenInput/wiki

Comment: I'm getting this error: TypeError: value is undefined
Line 657. This is the code in line 657 function highlight_term(value, term) {
return value.replace(new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + term + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<b>$1</b>");
} 
What seems to be the problem? Help!

Comment: I tested the demo (http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) in current versions of Chrome (on OSX), FF (onO OSX) and IE8. It worked in all of these.

Comment: Lacks Dynamic Source Support :((

Comment: @jasimmk - Nope, a function can be passed in place of the source variable.

Comment: Most of plugins are outdated, many won't work with new JQuery versions. This one is best I found: http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/.

Comment: The Best!! exactly what i needed,I can't imagine my life without Stackoverflow. :)

Answer (score 28):

This one very good! https://github.com/wuyuntao/jquery-autosuggest/

> ### How To Use It
>
> Obviously you need to make sure you have the latest jQuery library (at
>   least 1.3) already loaded in your page. After that it's really simple,
>   just add the following code to your page (make sure to wrap your code
>   in jQuery's ready function):
>
> ```
> $(function(){
>     $("input[type=text]").autoSuggest(data);
> });
> ```
>
> The above line of code will apply AutoSuggest to all text type `input`
>   elements on the page. Each one will be using the same set of Data. If
>   you want to have multiple AutoSuggest fields on your page that use
>   different sets of Data, make sure you select them separately. Like
>   this:
>
> ```
> $(function(){
>     $("div.someClass input").autoSuggest(data);
>     $("#someID input").autoSuggest(other_data);
> });
> ```
>
> Doing the above will allow you to pass in different options and
>   different Data sets. Below is an example of using AutoSuggest with a
>   Data Object and other various options:
>
> ```
> var data = {items: [
>     {value: "21", name: "Mick Jagger"},
>     {value: "43", name: "Johnny Storm"},
>     {value: "46", name: "Richard Hatch"},
>     {value: "54", name: "Kelly Slater"},
>     {value: "55", name: "Rudy Hamilton"},
>     {value: "79", name: "Michael Jordan"}
> ]};
> $("input[type=text]").autoSuggest(data.items, {selectedItemProp: "name", searchObjProps: "name"});
> ```

Comment: This is by far the best autosuggest plugin out there. It does not let the user add dupelicate records!

Comment: feature rich, but tons of bugs. In the end, I created my own: http://the.deerchao.net/TagEditor

Comment: @deerchao your work is very very nice ,just wanted to know if I can bound it with C# code ?I mean the tags ,also how to do it on the fly with web services ,thanks

Comment: @user1074474 By default, it only supports JSON data retrieved from a url. But there are all the source, you could customize it all you want.

Comment: @deerchao did you have any update on this plugin? I'm trying to use but get this error `TypeError: $$.autocomplete is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

close: function () {` any help?

Comment: @ReynierPM Sorry I was on vacation. Have you figured out what's wrong?

Comment: Yes @deerchao it's working now. Anyway thanks :) and I hope you've good vacations I need one too ...

Answer (score 22):

Here's what I've found, in no particular order:

- [Selectize.js](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/)
- [jQuery Tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) -- [GitHub](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput)
- [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/)
- [TextboxList](http://www.devthought.com/projects/jquery/textboxlist/)
- [Tag-it](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/) -- [GitHub](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it)
- [TextExt](http://textextjs.com/)
- [FCBKcomplete](http://www.emposha.com/javascript/fcbkcomplete.html) -- [GitHub](https://github.com/emposha/FCBKcomplete) -- [demo](http://www.emposha.com/demo/fcbkcomplete_2/)
- [jQuery Facebook Autocomplete](https://wharsojo.wordpress.com/2008/02/18/jquery-facebook-autocomplete/)
- [jquery-autosuggest](https://github.com/wuyuntao/jquery-autosuggest/) -- [drewwilson demo](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin)
- [Pines Tags](http://pinesframework.org/ptags/)
- [tagedit](http://tagedit.webwork-albrecht.de/)
- [Tagit](http://webspirited.com/tagit/)
- [jQuery Tags Input](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/)
- [Tags](http://getkirby.com/blog/panel-tags-field/demo)
- [jquery.token-field](http://sbfaulkner.github.com/jquery.token-field/)

Comment: nice collection, thanx.

Comment: Which are the top 2 or 3?

Answer (score 4):

if you are looking for user mentions feature like fb and tw, this is good plugin http://podio.github.io/jquery-mentions-input/

Answer (score 3):

This is the original JQuery autocomplete plugin before it was integrated into JQueryUI.
If you are looking to serve just JQuery but not the entire JQueryUI library, use this one.
I have used this one in the past and have been happy with it.

[http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/)/

Answer (score 1):

I found this one. Seems robust, well-maintained and is responsive.

http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Answer (score 0):

I was quite impressed with the [devbridge](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/) autosuggest. Highly customizable