# How to create a Facebook style autocomplete list with multiple options select

Tags: jquery, facebook, autocomplete

I want to create a facebook style auto-complete where you can have several options encircled in a bubble. More can be added and each may be removed non-sequentially.

Comment: an image would do you no harm :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook style JQuery autocomplete plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191807/facebook-style-jquery-autocomplete-plugin)

Answer (score 2):

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ is a useful javascript gadget library for this problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is what your looking for

http://www.emposha.com/javascript/fcbkcomplete.html

It uses JQuery, but you didn't specify if it mattered.