# Multi-Select Dropdown with size of 1

Tags: html, select, html-select

Is there any way of creating a combo box (`<select>`) with a size of 1? All the examples I can find allow for multiple selects but with a number of options visible at any one time. If this cannot be accomplished with bog standard HTML is it possible in a JS library such as JQuery?

Comment: Apparently it's the number of displayed elements.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: My post does not answer the question, but the comments might clarify the question.

What you want is to set the attribute `size` to 1, i.e.:

```
<select size="1" name="...">
    <option value="...">...</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Tom,

It must allow for multiple items to be selected at once, not just one.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I don't know of any possibility to achieve this using standard HTML.

Comment: Then you should set multiple="multiple" for <select> and height:xx i guess

Comment: My vision of such a thing would be perhaps a <select> that you click that drops down a whole bunch of items allowing you to click the ones you like with the menu "closing" when the user clicks elsewhere. Doesn't look to be possible does it? Sounds like I might need to look into creating a custom combo box although I'm not quite sure where to begin with that.

Comment: How about a list of checkboxes inside a div? You could have the div slide down when some event happens, and slide up again when you don't need it any more. If you think this could work for you, you could have a look at qtip (http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/).

Comment: `size="1"` works and will result in a select with a height of 1 as expected. It's not super usable but it is usable as you can still scroll through the options and select them. Personally I've used it to keep things visually aligned when JS isnt loaded

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that would be usability nightmare. What is the more general goal you are trying to achieve? I'm sure better solutions already exist.

I could guess you need something like [tag editor widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191807/facebook-style-jquery-autocomplete-plugin).