# jQuery plugin for autocompletion of hometown

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, user-interface, jquery-plugins

I am wondering if there is a readymade jquery/ajax/javascript plugin that hooks into an API of somesorts that provides a similar result to facebook hometown autocompletion in the profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [JqueryUI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

[Here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) is a good example with cities completion, reusing third party cities API

**UPD:** If you don't like it for some reason, take a look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191807/facebook-style-jquery-autocomplete-plugin) with a similar question. May be a bit outdated though.