# Any one know a jQuery based autocomplete plugin similar to the one in Facebook's email form?

Tags: jquery, facebook, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

In the form, you can start typing a friend's name, 
suggestions from your friend's list is offered (even has profile thumbnails), 
then you can select the profile which appears in the "to" field. 
There is styling to the selected profile in the input field, so this is not doable with the normal jQuery autocomplete plugin.

I did some search on web but so far I didn't find anything concrete or reliable one.

Comment: And why can't you do this using CSS and jQuery UI autocomplete?

Comment: When you say "normal jQuery autocomplete plugin" do you mean the [jQuery UI one](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)?

Comment: @phil yes i was talking about jquery UI

Comment: @jthompson hummm just making sure if something is already out there... would save me lot of time and hair

Comment: @Stephen, i wish solution to every problem was jQuery plugin lol

Comment: Yes - but you still have to customize it for your needs. Where do the profile images come from? What do you want it to look like?

Comment: @jthompson, yes i guess i would have to send some formatted htmls. Profile images, email address, name are store in db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe any of these links?

- http://www.emposha.com/javascript/fcbkcomplete.html
- http://wharsojo.wordpress.com/2008/02/18/jquery-facebook-autocomplete/
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget/
- [Facebook style JQuery autocomplete plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191807/facebook-style-jquery-autocomplete-plugin)

Comment: thax a lot found this plugin in one of links that u gave, perfect fit for me
http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin

Comment: Your welcome. That's what stackoverflow is about to me. Trying to help people and not just downvoting people because I can get a boner out of it ....