# Want jQuery code for facebook like suggestion with textbox search

Tags: jquery, facebook, autocomplete

this is what i exatly want in jquery code withour fbml.

[image]

Comment: i want auto complete i wnat this type suggestion box with text box search
http://demos.99points.info/facebook_suggest_box/

Comment: this is what i exatly want in jquery code withour fbml.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/WNr1Z.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer below links

http://www.web2ajax.fr/examples/facebook_searchengine/

[Facebook style JQuery autocomplete plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191807/facebook-style-jquery-autocomplete-plugin)

Thanks.

Comment: no i dont want auto complete i wnat this type suggestion box with text box search
http://demos.99points.info/facebook_suggest_box/

Comment: this is what i exatly want in jquery code withour fbml.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/WNr1Z.png

Answer (score 0):

You could try the jquery-ui autocomplete:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

I hope this meets your needs. If not, just tell us.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: I've used this module before, and I'm pretty sure it could be adapted to work with a textbox input, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: no i dont want auto complete i wnat this type suggestion box with text box search
http://demos.99points.info/facebook_suggest_box/

Comment: this is what i exatly want in jquery code withour fbml.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/WNr1Z.png