# django-tagging like app for specific conditions in django

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-tagging

I am making a project where I want to build a user profile. In this user profile, I want to provide the field for employers and skills. Both of these fields have many to many relationship. One user can have multiple employers and each employer can have different users linked to it. The same is for skills.

To the user I want to provide a field, where it can enter the employers separated by space, and also provide `Add another employer` button. This is very similar to `django-tagging` application.

But I cannot put the `tagfield` there because my tags are very generic and span across different models. I am using an `tagging-autocomplete` on it. And I just want the employers to come in the autocomplete field and not just any tag.

This can be done using `ManyToMany` fields but I have not found any good tutorial that shows how I can do that.

Any help or direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I belive,  it is not similar how django-tagging works inside, because what you need is just a widget to select users. And this widget should have autocomplete.

Take a look at the answers on [Facebook style JQuery autocomplete plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191807/facebook-style-jquery-autocomplete-plugin) question.

Comment: But how will I setup the ManytoMany fields? And why I am saying it is similar to `django-tagging` because we can enter multiple tags separated by spaces in a `tagfield`

Comment: TagField is just a helper, it is not neccessary to establish connection between the object and it's tags.