# What libraries are available for contextual auto completion in javascript?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, autosuggest

I currently use #Slack and I find its auto complete functionality very refreshing, as I am able to type in `#` and it will return a list of available commands, as well as me typing `@` and it will return a list of available users for me to notify.

So I was wondering what auto complete libraries there are out there that allow contextual auto completion rather than it just being the first letters entered. Here is an example of what I mean:

[image: Example of contextual autocomplete]

I know that there is jquery ui autocomplete, but could not find much resource on how to get it to act contextual rather than just on first entry and a search for contextual autocomplete does not bring back much results. I know stackoverflow does something similar for its tags so it may just be the correct terminology for this behaviour that I need to constrain my search, but if anyone can point me in the direction of some way to achieve this functionality without hand rolling it, I would be very happy :)

Comment: HAve you had a look at this ? https://github.com/gdbate/jquery-tweetbox

Comment: have not seen that one, I was just using slack and wondered how they did that auto complete, and after googling I found a few autocompletion frameworks (the common ones like jqui) but none of them were contextual, which I found puzzling, hence the question to find out what contextual ones are out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far this *seems* to be the closest thing I can find:
https://github.com/podio/jquery-mentions-input

And also it appears that `autosuggest` is also a thing, so that may be more inline with what I am after, I will not accept this answer in the hope that someone else can point me at a library or even tell me what library #Slack uses to achieve its functionality.

As I already have 3 people wanting to close the question I will assume this will crash and burn in about 5 minutes so incase anyone else is a bit confused as to what you should be looking for here was the only other useful SO article I found relating to this topic.

[Facebook style JQuery autocomplete plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191807/facebook-style-jquery-autocomplete-plugin)

== UPDATE ==

In the end I finally found: https://github.com/yuku-t/jquery-textcomplete which fits my scenario perfectly and seems maintained, so this would be the one I would opt for.

Answer (score 0):

Complete.ly is a more complete solution : http://complete-ly.appspot.com/ You can define what will be acceptable knowing different context.